# jQuery UI: Toggle autocomplete again after selecting data.

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui, autocomplete

I have a special scenario: 
When user selected an item from an autocomplete jQuery, it will toggle again the autocomplete to have another set of suggestion or set of source. How can I do that? Below is my code:

```
$('#JourneyStartLocation').autocomplete({
        source: function (request, response) {
            $.ajax({
                url: '@Url.Action("AutocompleteFindLocation", "Home")',
                type: "Get",
                dataType: "json",
                data: { SearchValue: $('#JourneyStartLocation').val(), Country: $('#JourneyCountryStart_code').val(), PcaId: $('#JourneyLocationStart_code').val() },
                success: function (data) {
                    response($.map(data, function (item) {
                        return {
                            label: item.Name,
                            value: item.Name + "/" + item.EntityType + "/" + item.Latitude + "/" + item.Longitude + "/" + item.LocationId
                        }
                    }))
                }
            });
        },
        minLength: 2,
        focus: function(event, ui) {
            $("#JourneyStartLocation").val(ui.item.label);
            return false;
        },
        select: function (event, ui) {
            //splitting the selected item to assign values
            var selectedItem = ui.item.value;
            var values = selectedItem.split('/');

            // assign values : name, entity type, latitude, longitude, lastId, next field
            $('#JourneyStartLocation').val(values[0]);
            $('#JourneyStartLocationTemp').val(values[0]);
            $('#JourneyStartLocationEntityType').val(values[1]).trigger('change');
            $('#JourneyStartLocationEntityTypeTemp').val(values[1]);
            $('#JourneyStartLatitude').val(values[2]);
            $('#JourneyStartLongitude').val(values[3]);
            $('#StartLocationId').val(values[4]);
            $('#JourneyLocationStart_code').val(values[5]);
            $('#JourneyStartLocationNextField').val(values[6]); 

            // The special scenario here
            if($('#JourneyStartLocationNextField').val() == "Find"){
               //toggle autocomplete again for another set of suggestion 
               // or another set from source
            }
            return false;
        }
    });
```

Big thanks for the help.

Comment: Can you provide a codepen or something where we can test your code?

Comment: Im Sorry. Its quite complex because I am using an API. Have you heard PCA-Predict? That was Im trying to do. Im not really quite sure how to replicate the way PCA Predict retrieve data.